# C#- How to parallel for each for list of methods?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task, parallel.foreach

I have list of methods and need to make parallelize them.
How to do that in C#? I see that there is a Parallel namespace?How to use it?

```
method1()
method2()
method3()
method4()
```

Answer (score 5):

[Parallel.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992634(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
Parallel.Invoke(
    () => method1(),
    () => method2(),
    () => method3(),
    () => method4()
)
```

Add namespace `System.Threading.Tasks`

Comment: It still stuck while invoking them? I don't know why?

Comment: @Hanaa `Parallel.Invoke` will wait while all methods complete. If you need run them and go futher use `Task.Run(() => method1())`

Comment: Please, could you check this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555945/parallelize-minimize-time-reading-number-of-sheets-from-excel-file

Answer (score 2):

You can create a list of `Action` delegate where each delegate is a call to a given method:

```
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>
{
     method1,
     method2,
     method3
};
```

And then use [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001(v=vs.110).aspx) to call them in parallel:

```
Parallel.ForEach(actions, action => action());
```