# Parallelize, minimize time Reading number of sheets from Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, multithreading, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I have Excel file has 4 sheets, all sheets have huge number of records around 144564 record.

In my code, fill_data method will call 4 methods, each method read one sheet.
the normal time it takes now is 7.02 minutes.

```
fill_data ()
{
    Excel.Application ExcelApplication;
    Excel.Workbooks ExcelWorkbooks;
    Excel.Workbook ExcelWorkbook1;

    ExcelApplication = new Excel.Application();  /// ApplicationClass()
    ExcelWorkbooks = ExcelApplication.Workbooks;
    try
    {
                ExcelWorkbook1 = ExcelApplication.Workbooks.Open(fileName1, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true);
    }
    catch
    {
                return;
    }

    active1 = ExcelWorkbook1.Worksheets.get_Item(1); // students list
    active2 = ExcelWorkbook2.Worksheets.get_Item(2);
    active3 = ExcelWorkbook3.Worksheets.get_Item(3);
    active4 = ExcelWorkbook4.Worksheets.get_Item(4);

    fill_students();
    fill_instructors();
    fill_exams();
    fill_rooms();
```

}

```
 public static void fill_students(){
      Excel.Worksheet active = active1;
      //Read all Cells at Sheet
 }
```

I try to use the Parallel feature to make the 4 methods run in parallel, instead of explicitly call methods I use invoke at Parallel class. As the following:

```
fill_data ()
{
    .....
    Parallel.Invoke(
            () => fill_students(),
            () => fill_instructors(),
            () => fill_exams(),
            () => fill_rooms()
        );
}
```

There is no enhancement on the executing time! it was 7.12 minutes!
So what is going wrong? how to minimize this time?

Comment: The Excel COM calls are inherently single-threaded. If multiple threads try to access the data the COM calls automatically block all but one thread at a time. It is impossible to multi-thread this.

Comment: Also, you're doing IO. It's unlikely that making your code multi-threaded would produce any significant improvement in any case. Multi-threading only really helps CPU intensive operations.

Comment: can't we optimize the time?

Comment: what do you think if I read 4 sheets from different files, then we have a 4 ExcelApplication = new Excel.Application(); to read each sheet.

Comment: This couldn't help ?

Comment: If you have Excel running in four different processes then you still will run against an IO limit. If all four take 7 minutes then running four processes you might find that the first one takes 6.9 minutes and the last three about 0.2 minutes each. Only one way to find out though.

Comment: What you should do is read the excel file using an approach which reads the file directly rather than via COM. You might find that they will load in seconds.

Comment: Have a read of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996234/optimal-way-to-read-an-excel-file-xls-xlsx/12996544#12996544

Comment: Thank you, I will check this way :)

Comment: the fastest way to write excel files - use OpenXml SDK. It allows to stream writing file as xml https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx

Comment: @Backs, I need to read excel

Comment: @Hanaa read also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102010/open-xml-reading-from-excel-file